# How to get values after form submit

Tags: forms

I created on custom module to generate a form with this code

```
function report_page_form_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $meberArr = array();
    $form['field_member_org']=array(
        '#type'=>'select',
        '#options'=> $meberArr,
    );
    $form['field_start_date'] = array(
      '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
      '#type' => 'date_popup',
      '#weight'=>0,
    );
    $form['field_end_date'] = array(
      '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
      '#type' => 'date_popup',
      '#weight'=>0,
    );
// Provide a submit button.
          $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'Filter',
          );
return $form;
 }
```

In one of my `node--nid.tpl.php`, I am rendering this form as

```
 $arr = drupal_get_form('report_page_form_form');
 print drupal_render($arr);
```

I am writing an SQL query in the same `node--nid.tpl.php` file to fetch data from DB.

```
SELECT TITLE FROM REPORT WHERE ....
```

I need to pass form submitted values to this query. Can anyone help me to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get the values of the submitted form in `hook_form_submit`

```
function MY_MODULE_NAME_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
         //your code here
        }
```

You would get all the required values in `$form_state['values']`

Comment: Thanks Aparna. i need the $form_state['values'] in my node--nid.tpl.php. Is that possible instead of new module.

Comment: You could try report_page_form_form_submit. I hope it will work